# How can I left outer join SQL Server using on?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to join two tables into master table (on to many) but I keep getting an error

> Incorrect syntax near C.showdepartmentinventory_id

My code:

```
CREATE VIEW view_transactionshowidea 
AS
    SELECT 
        A.showidea_id, A.showideaupdatetype_id, A.showidea_proposedtitle,
        A.showidea_fixtitle, 
        B.showinventorycategory_id, B.showinventorycategory_name,
        C.showinventorydepartment_id, C.showinventorydepartment_name,
        A.shoidea_duration, A.showidea_segment, A.showidea_PIC, 
        A.showidea_concept, A.showidea_isdisabled
    FROM 
        transaction_showidea AS A 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        view_showideainventory AS B 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        view_showideainventorydepartment AS C ON showinventorycategory_id = B.showinventorycategory_id 
                                              AND showinventorycategory_name = C.showinventorydepartment_id
```

What is the problem with my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `JOIN` should be followed by its `ON` clause.  The sources of your `JOIN` keys are not clear, but something like this:

```
FROM transaction_showidea si LEFT OUTER JOIN
     view_showideainventory sii
     ON si.showinventorycategory_id = sii.showinventorycategory_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
     view_showideainventorydepartment siid
     ON  sii.showinventorycategory_name = siid.showinventorydepartment_id
```

Note that this introduces *meaninful* table aliases -- abbreviations for the table names.  And all column references are qualified.

Comment: Thank you, i thinks it sgot answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify "ON" right after your join statement like this:

```
CREATE VIEW view_transactionshowidea AS
SELECT A.showidea_id, A.showideaupdatetype_id, A.showidea_proposedtitle,
       A.showidea_fixtitle, B.showinventorycategory_id, B.showinventorycategory_name,
       C.showinventorydepartment_id, C.showinventorydepartment_name,
       A.shoidea_duration, A.showidea_segment, A.showidea_PIC, A.showidea_concept, 
       A.showidea_isdisabled
FROM transaction_showidea AS A 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN view_showideainventory AS B on showinventorycategory_id = B.showinventorycategory_id
     LEFT OUTER JOIN view_showideainventorydepartment AS C ON  showinventorycategory_name = C.showinventorydepartment_id
```